# Replace MS word sub-documents template and setup with master-document configuration

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, templates, styles, master

Over a number of years on a project I have accumulated dozens if not hundreds of word files that I am structuring for viewing and editing purposes in a master word file.  These files are on a networked drive and are constantly being updated.  So since this is a collaborative effort the Master document is a reasonable approach because I can send the changes backwards to the sub documents in the same way the document will update with the current files (granted not simultaneously in real time but because of time changes this isn't an issue).

Problems I have noticed:

1. The files coming in are on different page sizes (letter, A4, tabloid, etc).  It's not terribly practical for me to try and open each one and reapply settings, there are too many files.
2. The styles in the normal.dot template file have been edited by different people to reflect personal taste.
3. I as the project maintainer are also constantly modifying and integrating new document styles and `VBA` macros into the main document template on my computer which the Master document reflects.

When I select all the page setup options disappear, and only the current document with the cursor reflects the page setup change.

Is there any way I can use the master document to create a universal hierarchy or formatting template that can be forced to override and replace these settings in all the sub documents?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that through the developer tab >> templates menu, I can do something rudimentary but essential equivalent to the template reset option.

This doesn't yet apply to the blanket master/sub document reset automation, just reseting sub documents, but I plan to write a piece of code to ensure that documents in a specific project share the same document template at all times.

When finished, and depending on the broadness/usefulness of this program/code I will include it here.